# Access VBA Shell command not working

Tags: vba, ms-access

so I'm trying to get a very simple shell command to execute a batch file that's created, but for some reason the shell command doesn't do anything.

The batch file gets created and when I double click on the batch file it executes the script just fine, but if I try to call the shell command in VBA it appears that it tries to open a command window, but immediately closes it after, not producing any errors. This code used to work fine before I reformatted this laptop AND this code works on another system running Server 2012 R2 (I'm running windows 10)

```
        Dim SedjaShell
        f = "C:\Temp\_SedjaScript.bat"
        Open f For Output As #1
        Print #1, Chr(34) & SedjaDir & Chr(34) & " merge --files " & Page1 & " " & Page2 & " " & TOS & " " & Disclosure & " --output " & OutputDir
        Print #1, "Pause"
        Close #1

        SedjaShell = Shell("C:\Temp\_SedjaScript.bat", 1)
```

Is there something I might be missing?

EDIT
Adding the contents of _SedjaScript.Bat

```
"C:\Users\User\Desktop\DealTracker\MergeFiles\sejda-console-3.0.4\bin\sejda-console.bat" merge --files C:\Temp\ContractSummary.pdf C:\Temp\Page2.pdf C:\Temp\TOS.pdf C:\Temp\Disclosure.pdf --output "C:\Users\User\Desktop\DealTracker\Completed Contracts\Company-Name-Inc-07-19-2017-Contract.pdf"
Pause
```

Comment: Are you sure it's not working? It could have done its thing and closed itself, as that's the default behavior of a batch script.

Comment: I know it's not working since the output file doesn't exist. I also just tried this exact same code on another system and it worked just fine. Also if it was working the script window would remain up since I added a pause condition at the end of the script. However if I manually launch the .bat file the script launches and outputs the merged file

Comment: Your batch file might be using relative paths. Try changing the working directory for the `Shell` command using `ChDir` (and `ChDrive` if required). If I had to guess, you'd want to do `ChDir "C:\Temp"`.

Comment: Nope that didn't work

Comment: Try displaying (Debug.Print or MsgBox) exactly what you're writing to the batch file.

Comment: Please add the content of _SedjaScript.bat to your question.

Comment: @Andre Done also reiterating that when I manually launch the .bat script it works just fine

Comment: Hmm, curious. I suggest to add two lines `set` and `pause` to the start of the batch you write. The tool looks like a Java program. Check that `PATH` and maybe `JAVA_HOME` are set correctly. The problem may be that you run the batch from 32-bit Access vs. from 64-bit Windows when run directly.

Comment: AWESOME That did it! after manually setting the path for my JRE bin it worked. Thanks for that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Andre I was able to get the script to work inside VBA's Shell command.

By setting the PATH for my JRE to `JAVA_HOME` I was able to successfully launch the script.

```
setx JAVA_HOME "C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_141"
setx PATH "%PATH%;%JAVA_HOME%\bin";
```